# Where does the JNLP secret come from?

Tags: jenkins

I am in the process of connecting a static slave to Jenkins master. The command Im going to use is :

```
java -jar <PATH>/slave.jar -jnlpUrl $JENKINS_MASTER_URL -secret $JNLP_SECRET
```

My question is where does the `$JNLP_SECRET` secret come from ?

If its something configured in the Jenkins Master, then where is it configured ?

And if I have access to that, can I just cope paste it into this command ?

A short explanation or link to documentation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I don't have the "where did the value come from" knowledge, but if you are a Jenkins administrator you can login to Jenkins, Manage Jenkins, Script Console, then run this script (script from here: [JENKINS-18342](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18342?focusedCommentId=188162&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-188162)):

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) 
{ println aSlave.name + "," + aSlave.getComputer().getJnlpMac() }
```

Also this documentation describes how you could do it if you aren't a Jenkins admin: [How to find JNLP Node's secret key remotely](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222520647-How-to-find-JNLP-Node-s-secret-key-remotely-)

Answer (score 4):

The `JNLP_SECRET` is passed as part of the slave-agent.jnlp you download to start your Jenkins slave.

You can extract the secret from this file as described [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222520647-How-to-find-JNLP-Node-s-secret-key-remotely-):

> You can download the “slave-agent.jnlp” file at $NODE_URL/slave-agent.jnlp. This file actually contains XML content that includes the secret.
>
> Here is an example of a JNLP file downloaded from a Jenkins instance at https://cje.example.com/computer/jnlpAgentTest/slave-agent.jnlp - the secret is `b8c80148ce36de10c9358384fac9e28fbba941055a9a6ab2277e75ddc29a8744`:
>
> ```
>   <jnlp codebase="https://cje.example.com/computer/jnlpAgentTest/" spec="1.0+">
>       <information>
>           <title>Agent for jnlpAgentTest</title>
>           <vendor>Jenkins project</vendor>
>           <homepage href="https://jenkins-ci.org/"/>
>       </information>
>       <security>
>           <all-permissions/>
>       </security>
>       <resources>
>           <j2se version="1.8+"/>
>           <jar href="https://cje.example.com/jnlpJars/remoting.jar"/>
>       </resources>
>       <application-desc main-class="hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main">
>           <argument>b8c80148ce36de10c9358384fac9e28fbba941055a9a6ab2277e75ddc29a8744</argument>
>           <argument>jnlpAgentTest</argument>
>           <argument>-workDir</argument>
>           <argument>/tmp/jnlpAgenttest</argument>
>           <argument>-internalDir</argument>
>           <argument>remoting</argument>
>           <argument>-url</argument>
>           <argument>https://cje.example.com/</argument>
>       </application-desc>
>   </jnlp>
> ```